# React js and Laravel Localization strings?

Tags: javascript, laravel-4, localization, reactjs

I recently started to give a go to React js and im starting to like it.

There is one logic what i am stuck with.

My site is multi-language and i have problems rendering the strings.

So what i thought is to place a `data-translate` attribute to the id's or classes but still does not fit right.

**This is just a basic example of my logic**

React js

```
var counter =  document.getElementById('counter').getAttribute('data-translate');

var Timer = React.createClass({


  getInitialState: function() {
    return {secondsElapsed: 0};
  },
  tick: function() {
    this.setState({secondsElapsed: this.state.secondsElapsed + 1});
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className={this.translate}>{counter} {this.state.secondsElapsed}</div>
    );
  }
});



React.renderComponent(
    <Timer />,
    document.getElementById('counter')
  );
```

HTML

```
<div id="counter" data-translate="{{ trans('stream.counter') }}"></div>
```

So not the best idea.

Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to convert your translation files into JSON and use a client side translation function.

For example, image you generated something like this:

```
var translations = {"en":{"stream":{"counter":"counter"}}};
```

You could then write trans like this:

```
function trans(key){
  var keys = key.split(".");
  var lang = navigator.language.split("-");
  return lang.concat(keys).reduce(function(o, k){
    var next = o[k];
    if (!next) {
      console.error('No translation found for ' + key, new Error().stack);
      return {};
    }
    else {
      return next;
    }
  }, translations);
}
```

And in your components, just use

```
<div>{trans('stream.counter')}</div>
```

Comment: This works great... I needed to change `if (next)` to `if(!next)` though

Answer (score 1):

An API like [gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) will do what you need. During application initialisation, you'd set up a dictionary with source keys being the "fallback language" text, and the values in the destination language.

```
// Data source initialised once, could be embedded in the source from the server.
var TranslationDictionary = {
    "the ticks": "les tiques",
    ...
};

// In the component:
return <div>{gettext("the ticks")}</div>;

// Then the gettext utility to join them together:
function gettext(lookup) {
    var translation = TranslationDictionary[lookup];
    if (translation) {
        return translation;
    }
    else {
        console.log("Warning: missing translation for: " + lookup);
        return lookup;
    }
}
```

The `gettext` function is then very simple, and since the keys are the full text in the fallback language, the view code is still easy to read. Bonus points if you write a code analyser which looks for missing translations.